# Help identify SMD part - and why is the last letter rotated?

Tags: transistors, pcb, diodes, surface-mount, identification

New to this. There're two parts in the image. I think one is a dual transistor and the other is a dual diode. But I couldn't pinpoint what they are.

And can someone explain why the last letter is rotated 90 degree?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your "MA" is a SOT363 dual NPN transistor, likely a [MBT3904DW1](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MBT3904DW1T1-D.PDF).  Your "A1" is also indeed a common anode dual diode in SOT23, likely a [BAW56](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BA/BAW56.pdf).  The sideways letter on both packages is most likely a date and/or production code.